# How can I extract the node names for fragmented XML document using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, xml, parsing, tags, nokogiri

I an XML-like document which is pre-processed by a system out of my control.  The format of the document is like this:

```
 <template>
Hello, there <RECALL>first_name</RECALL>.  Thanks for giving me your email.  
<SETPROFILE><NAME>email</NAME><VALUE><star/></VALUE></SETPROFILE>.  I have just sent you something.
</template>
```

However, I only get as a text string what is between the `<template>` tags.

I would like to be able to extract **without** specifying the tags ahead of time when parsing.  I can do this with the Crack gem but *only* if the tags are at the end of the string and there is only one.

With Crack, I can put a string like

```
string = "<SETPROFILE><NAME>email</NAME><VALUE>go@go.com</VALUE></SETPROFILE>"
```

and my output from Crack is:

```
{"SETPROFILE"=>{"NAME"=>"email", "VALUE"=>"go@go.com"}}
```

Then I can use a `case` statement for the possible values I care about.

Given that I need to have multiple `<tags>` in the string and they cannot be at the end of the string, how can I parse out the node names and the values easily, similar to what I do with crack?

These tags also need to be removed.  I would like to continue to use [the excellent suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27551806/how-do-i-remove-substring-from-a-string-in-ruby/27555394#27555394) from @TinMan.

It works perfectly once I know the name of the tag.  The number of tags will be finite.  I send the tag to the appropriate method once I know it, but it needs to get parsed out easily first.

Comment: This is a bit confusing. What do you want as output?

Comment: Output similar to crack would be a great. Parsed keys and associated values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Nokogiri, you can treat the string as a DocumentFragment, then find the embedded nodes:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse(<<EOT)
Hello, there <RECALL>first_name</RECALL>.  Thanks for giving me your email.  
<SETPROFILE><NAME>email</NAME><VALUE><star/></VALUE></SETPROFILE>.  I have just sent you something.
EOT

nodes = doc.search('*').each_with_object({}){ |n, h|
  h[n] = n.text
}

nodes # => {#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3ff96083b744 name="RECALL" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3ff96083a09c "first_name">]>=>"first_name", #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3ff96083b5c8 name="SETPROFILE" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3ff96083a678 name="NAME" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3ff960836884 "email">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3ff96083a650 name="VALUE" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3ff96083a5c4 name="star">]>]>=>"email", #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3ff96083a678 name="NAME" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3ff960836884 "email">]>=>"email", #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3ff96083a650 name="VALUE" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3ff96083a5c4 name="star">]>=>"", #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3ff96083a5c4 name="star">=>""}
```

Or, more legibly:

```
nodes = doc.search('*').each_with_object({}){ |n, h|
  h[n.name] = n.text
}

nodes # => {"RECALL"=>"first_name", "SETPROFILE"=>"email", "NAME"=>"email", "VALUE"=>"", "star"=>""}
```

Getting the content of a particular tag is easy then:

```
nodes['RECALL'] # => "first_name"
```

Iterating over all the tags is also easy:

```
nodes.keys.each do |k| 
  ... 
end
```

You can even replace a tag and its content with text:

```
doc.at('RECALL').replace('Fred')
doc.to_xml # => "Hello, there Fred.  Thanks for giving me your email.  \n<SETPROFILE>\n  <NAME>email</NAME>\n  <VALUE>\n    <star/>\n  </VALUE>\n</SETPROFILE>.  I have just sent you something.\n"
```

How to replace the nested tags is left to you as an exercise.

Comment: Thank you!  Will try this out shortly